# Regular expression multiple cut on string selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

1. My basic string structure :

Gestion des tickets - Compte 5 - SARL PROJET DE BLI[Commercial: SNOW Jon]

Explanation of decompose string :
 - "5" : an ID
 - "SARL PROJET DE BLI" : a company name
 - "SNOW Jon" : the full name of a sale agent, composed by "last name" + "first name"

2. What I've done and works :

   - store my structured string : `storeText | css=h1 | h13`
   - store the ID : `storeEval | storedVars['h13'].split(' ')[5] | final_id`
3. What I really needs : 2 regular expressions for store the 2 last one, company name and full name of sale agent. I need only what is between "" whithout useless space on begin and end.

I already try something like this :
`storeEval  |  storedVars['h13'].match(/- \/((?:.|<br />)*?) [/)  |  final_company`
But don't works ... perhaps the space ...
For company name i want store ALL BETWEEN "- " AND " ["
same for the full name : store ALL BETWEEN ": " AND "]"

Did someone have a solution ? I'm not very good with regular expression... in english too :p

Answer (score 0):

I finally find it myself, i try this and it works:

storeEval  |  storedVars['h13'].match(/- ([a-zA-Z ]+) [/)[1]  |  fi_rs

storeEval  |  storedVars['h13'].match(/\: ([^\]]+)\]/)[1]  |  fi_rs2

Bye.